# Move from EmitterProcessor to Sinks.many()

Tags: project-reactor

For some time have been using `create` an `EmitterProcessor` with built in `sink` as follows:

```
EmitterProcessor<String> emitter = EmitterProcessor.create();
FluxSink<String> sink = emitter.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);
```

The `sink` publishes using a `Flux` `.from` command

```
Flux<String> out = Flux
        .from(emitter
        .log(log.getName()));
```

and the `sink` can be passed around, and populated with strings, simply using the `next` instruction.

Now we see that `EmitterProcessor` is deprecated.

[image]

It's all replaced with [`Sinks.many()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#processors) like this

```
Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
```

but how to use that to publish `from`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was casting the `Sinks.many()` to `asFlux()`

```
Flux<String> out = Flux
        .from(sink.asFlux()
        .log(log.getName()));
```

Also using that for cancel and termination of the flux

```
sink.asFlux().doOnCancel(() -> {
    cancelSink(id, request);
});
    
/* Handle errors, eviction, expiration */
sink.asFlux().doOnTerminate(() -> {
    disposeSink(id);
});
```

*UPDATE* The cancel and terminate don't appear to work per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66464896/in-reactor-sinks-many-what-is-equivalent-to-emitterprocessor-oncancel)