# Where a Reactor Sink.Many() should have 1 consumer should use unicast or multicast

Tags: project-reactor

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462992/move-from-emitterprocessor-to-sinks-many/) I have updated from deprecated `EmitterProcessor` to `Sinks.Many()` with the following

```
Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
```

The `sink` is filled with `String` as required and feeds back to a spring boot endpoint. Each client should have their own session via the endpoint.

Though should I be using

```
Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
```

I want to drop messages to slow consumers.