# In Reactor Sinks.Many() what is equivalent to EmitterProcessor onCancel

Tags: project-reactor

Per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462992/move-from-emitterprocessor-to-sinks-many) I used to have code

```
EmitterProcessor<String> emitter = EmitterProcessor.create();
FluxSink<String> sink = emitter.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);

sink.onCancel(() -> {
  cancelSink(id, request);
});
```

and when for example with `rSocket` a browser opened a session and asked for some data, calling the `EmitterProcessor` when a client shut down their browser the `publisher` like

```
Flux<String> out = Flux
    .from(emitter
    .log(log.getName()));
```

would know that the Flux subscriber was cancelled (when a browser was closed) and that would call the `onCancel` handle.

With `Sinks.Many()` I have implemented

```
Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

sink.asFlux().doOnCancel(() -> {
    cancelSink(id, request);
});

Flux<String> out = Flux
    .from(sink.asFlux()
    .log(log.getName()));
```

and the strings are published via a flux to the browser, but when the client closes the session there is no longer the `onCancel` to handle some tidying up.

It looks like this was [discussed here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2394) and also [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/283) but I don't understand the solutions. What is it please?

Comment: I see you're no longer specifying the overflow strategy with the new way, Do you know how to set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sink.asFlux().doOnCancel(...)` and `sink.asFlux()` are two different instances. You're not reusing the one where you have set up cancel handling logic, and that is why you don't observe the `cancelSink` cleanup on your `out` variable.

Do something more like:

```
Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

Flux<String> fluxWithCancelSupport = sink.asFlux().doOnCancel(() -> {
    cancelSink(id, request);
});

Flux<String> out = fluxWithCancelSupport
    .log(log.getName()));
```

(PS: you don't need the `Flux.from(sink.asFlux())` since the later already gives you a `Flux`).

Comment: Thanks, so the use case is to use the sink (or flux?) to send out random updates coming from another queue. It was using `tryEmitNext(String)` to emit (or publish?) the queue message out to the flux subscriber. Is there a `Flux<String>` equivalent to `tryEmitNext` as used by `Many<String>` sink ? Thanks...

Comment: Or, as i have done now, is a recommended approach to use the sink `tryEmitNext` to handle the queue *and then* cast `asFlux` to publish back to the caller...

Comment: I think the second approach, if I understand it correctly. My answer just meant to say that your snippet basically ignores the result of `sink.asFlux().doOnCancel(...)`, so the runnable in there will never be invoked.

Comment: yes, thank's that's great i have the flow kind of working now, but I have run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888735/in-reactor-flux-an-oncancel-call-is-not-returned-to-calling-method) i am still missing something about flux lifecycles?

Comment: all implementations of asFlux() will return same instance of flux. So first sentence of this answer is not correct. Other side is, that this should be done using `flux = sink.asFlux; flux....`