# In Reactor Flux an onCancel call is not returned to calling method

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a set of methods that handle a `Flux<String>` so

```
@GetMapping(value = "/web/{s}")
public Flux<String> getWeb(@PathVariable String s) {
    return myService.getFlux(s);
}
```

In the `service` class:

```
public Flux<String> getFlux(String json) throws Exception {
    return handleRequest(json);
}

private Flux<String> handleRequest(String json) throws Exception {
    Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();

    ... do stuff with sink ... 

    /* Handle flux completion, termination, error */
    Flux<String> webFlux = sink.asFlux()
            .doOnTerminate(() -> { disposeSink(id); })
            .doOnComplete(() -> { completeSink(id); })
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> { terminateSink(id); }) 
            .doOnCancel(() -> { cancelSink(id); })

    return webFlux;
}
```

When I get the client to cut short, cancel, terminate their request before it completes, the `doOnCancel` call only works if it is attached to the initial calling method, i.e.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/web/{s}")
public Flux<String> getWeb(@PathVariable String s) {
    return myService.getFlux(s).doOnCancel(() -> Log.Info("Cancelled"));
}
```

This is not really where I want to put it, although it makes sense given it's the client facing call. Why doesn't the `doOnCancel` hook in the `service` class get back to the caller? Is a flux that's passed back to calling methods kind of publishing / subscribing to itself ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bit weird but I had to return the `sink.asFlux()` with the hooks directly like this:

```
private Flux<String> handleRequest(String json) throws Exception {
    Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();

    ... do stuff with sink ... 

    /* Handle flux completion, termination, error */
    return sink.asFlux()
        .doOnTerminate(() -> { disposeSink(id); })
        .doOnComplete(() -> { completeSink(id); })
        .doAfterTerminate(() -> { terminateSink(id); }) 
        .doOnCancel(() -> { cancelSink(id); });
}
```

Then on the client facing class everything worked when the client randomly cancels the request. I also put the `log()` in that class

```
@GetMapping(value = "/web/{s}")
public Flux<String> getWeb(@PathVariable String s) {
    return myService.getFlux(s).log();
}
```

So basically there is no direct `Flux` initialization just transform a `sink.asFlux()` the one time and `return` it back up the stack.